# Update UserControl when ObservableCollection is modified

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I made a `UserControl` that works good, except that it doesn't take changes when I modify my `ObservableCollection<>`.

Here is my ViewModel, where I update every 5 seconds my ObservableCollection :

```
private ObservableCollection<WarningMessage> listWarnings = new ObservableCollection<WarningMessage>();
public ObservableCollection<WarningMessage> ListWarnings { get { return this.listWarnings; } set { this.listWarnings = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ListWarnings"); } }

...

private void updateWarnings()
{
    this.ListWarnings.Clear();
    foreach(WarningMessage warning in this.listWarningsTemp)
    {
        this.ListWarnings.Add(warning);
    }
}
```

The `ListWarnings` is updated correctly, as in the header of window, I Bind to it correctly, but the value is not passed to `UserControl`.

Here is my .xaml of my main window, here I have a column in a ListView that displays the UserControl :

```
<GridViewColumn                                                     Header="" Width="40">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Tag="{Binding}">
                <Grid>
                    <views:UserControlListWarnings
        MainObject = "{Binding}"
        ListWarnings="{Binding DataContext.ListWarnings, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Then the UserControl itself :

```
public partial class UserControlListWarnings : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string nomPropriete)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nomPropriete));
    }
    public UserControlListWarnings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static DependencyProperty ListWarningsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ListWarnings),
            typeof(IList<WarningMessage>),
            typeof(UserControlListWarnings),
            new PropertyMetadata(ListWarningsPropertyChanged));

    public IList<WarningMessage> ListWarnings
    {
        get { return (IList<WarningMessage>)GetValue(ListWarningsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListWarningsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty MainObjectProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(MainObject),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(UserControlListWarnings),
            new PropertyMetadata(MainObjectPropertyChanged));

    public object MainObject
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(MainObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainObjectProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void ListWarningsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControlListWarnings userControl = (UserControlListWarnings)obj;
        if(e.NewValue is ObservableCollection<WarningMessage> list)
        {
            userControl.ListWarnings = list;
        }
        updateView(userControl);
    }
    private static void MainObjectPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControlListWarnings userControl = (UserControlListWarnings)obj;
        updateView(userControl);
    }
    
    private List<string> listMessages { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> ListMessages { get { return listMessages; } set { listMessages = value; } }
    private List<WarningMessage> listWarningMessages { get; set; } = new List<WarningMessage>();
    public List<WarningMessage> ListWarningMessages { get { return this.listWarningMessages; } set { this.listWarningMessages = value; } }
    private string imagePath { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get { return this.imagePath; } set { this.imagePath = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath"); } }
    private string imageVoid { get; set; }
    public string ImageVoid { get { return this.imageVoid; } set { this.imageVoid = value; } }
    private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ListWarningMessages = this.ListWarningMessages;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why, but when I edit `ListWarnings`, then `ListWarningsPropertyChanged` is never executed. Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you ever set `ListWarning = ...` in the view model? Probably not. Adding and removing items does not change the value of the property `ListWarning `. You probably have to listen to the CollectionChanged event of the list.

Comment: @KlausGütter no in fact I don't, I also noticed that if I do so, the event is launched, but in that case I lose the binding in my main Window. Or may have a different list for my main window, and for the UserControl?

Comment: No,, as I said, subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection if you want to be informed about Additions and Deletions.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes in fact I have big problems with that, but thanks to your advise (was missing keyword CollectionChanged), I found another topic with the same issue. Then CollectionChanged doesn't exist for IList, I changed my IList to ObservableCollection then added the CollectionChanged. Not sure it is the cleanest way as I did, but it works. Thanks (subscribe to the CollectionChanged : excsue me, but for me it was not so obvious how to do that).